# Aggregate queries & Comos DB table storage api

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

According to the [Table API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction) introduction page for Cosmos DB one of the advantages while querying data over using the traditional Azure Table Storage is that it supports aggregates. However, after doing some extensive searching I've haven't encountered any indication within the SDK's for there is a way to execute aggregates.

Is there any clear example as to how work execute aggregate queries on data with the Table Storage API? Also if there are limitations on the available aggregates with Table API is there a list somewhere of supported and unsupported aggregates?

Example: I have a couple thousand records which each have a date and temperature value. Now what I want to be able to do is get the average temperature of the last hour etc. In SQL it would look something like:

> Select AVG(temperature) from table where date >= xxx.

Is this possible with the Table Storage API or is this "feature" only available when working with the DocumentDB API?

I open for a solution/example with any of the available sdk's.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Document API directly on the data stored?

Just an educated guess, because I haven't done anything with the Table API yet, but given the multi-model nature (ie. the ability to do Cross API stuff), I can imagine you can aggregate your way down with the Document API if it's that what is required.

https://blog.spectologic.com/2017/06/30/digging-into-cosmosdb-storage/